# Apple Search Ads returning error while "groupBy" clause

Tags: api, curl, apple-search-ads

I have setup a tool to query the Apple Search Ads API, the documentation for which can be found [here](https://searchads.apple.com/v/advanced/help/b/docs/pdf/management-api.pdf).
One can pass a "groupBy" clause to the request, like so:

```
curl -X POST https://api.searchads.apple.com/api/v1/reports/campaigns  \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json'  \
-H 'Authorization: orgId=1056160'  \
-E pem.pem --key key.key \
-d '{"selector": {"pagination": {"limit": 10, "offset": 0}, "orderBy": [{"sortOrder": "DESCENDING", "field": "campaignId"}]}, "returnRecordsWithNoMetrics": false, "granularity": "DAILY", "returnRowTotals": false, "timeZone": "UTC", "endTime": "2019-03-27", "startTime": "2019-02-27", "groupBy": "countryCode"}' \
| python -m json.tool
```

and expect back data grouped by `countryCode`.

However, since 23 April, 2019, the API began to return an error:

```
{
    "data": null,
    "error": {
        "errors": [
            {
                "field": "Line#:1 Column#:292",
                "message": "This is an invalid request. At least one field format is not readable by the system.",
                "messageCode": "INVALID_ATTRIBUTE_TYPE"
            }
        ]
    },
    "pagination": null
}
```

I tried looking for help online but have come short so far.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What reporting endpoint are you hitting?

reports/campaigns?

If it's campaigns endpoint, try this payload:

```
{
    "startTime": "2019-02-27",
    "endTime": "2019-03-27",
    "granularity": "DAILY",
    "selector": {
        "orderBy": [
            {
                "field": "campaignId",
                "sortOrder": "DESCENDING"
            }
        ],
        "conditions": [
        ],
        "pagination": {
            "offset": 0,
            "limit": 10
        }
    },
     "groupBy": [
        "countryCode"
    ],
    "timeZone": "UTC",
    "returnRecordsWithNoMetrics": false,
    "returnRowTotals": false,
    "returnGrandTotals": false
}
```

Comment: @mastersifu, adding the `groupBy` clause as an array instead of a string, worked. Thanks!